# I'm no longer getting proper exception messages in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I keep getting this:

```
09-04 11:14:10.541 7023-7023/com.gmail.gogobebe2.thedayahead W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419ccc50)
```

and a message "Unfortunately, The Day Ahead has stopped" on my phone.

As well as these error messages: http://pastebin.com/24RU2k5X

But never an actual Exception stacktrace like i used to.

Here's the github link to the project code: https://github.com/gogobebe2/TheDayAhead

Answer (score 0):

Solved lol, I just did:

```
try {
    all code here
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("asdasd", ex.getMessage());
}
```

This is the only way I can figure out the error message when debugging. I think my android studio version is bugged.

**Edit:** I just tried running the app on my dad's phone and he gets the exceptions in the logcat show up just fine but when I try it with my phone, it doesn't. So weird.

Comment: From the logs you posted it looks like your are trying to use a method that is not availble on the version of android your device/emulator is running on.